# Div inside divs, mess up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a "site", in this site I got three buttons which switch between 3 ...windows(?). This is done with a function which hides 2 while keeping one visible. the three "windows" are divs.
The function which hides and makes the divs visible targets children of "id="wrapper" ", It shouldn't target Wrappers grand children and hence the problem shouldn't be in there, but the function is the only thing that could intefer, as far as I know.

One of the three divs, has divs inside of it with no issue, but the other divs can't contain divs and I had to use `<p>`'s to contain stuff, but that doesn't work as well when I want to use images as buttons and such.

I've gone over the html several times the past day but I can't find any issue in it, I would keep trying on my own but I may lose my internet in 1-3 days and I don't want to be "stranded".

My three "wrapper" children are, class "WindowTwo", "WindowThree" and "container". If you put a div inside WindowTwo and WindowThree you'll notice the first button window goes blank. 
Container is the one that can contain divs inside divs with no problem

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbjzWL

I know my code is messy and my blabbering messier, sorry for that and thanks in advance for any inputs :)

```js
function toggleDiv(target) {
  var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName("div");
  
  if (target == 1) {
    div[0].style.display = 'block';
    div[1].style.display = 'none';
    div[2].style.display = 'none';
  } else if (target == 2) {
    div[0].style.display = 'none';
    div[1].style.display = 'block';
    div[2].style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div[0].style.display = 'none';
    div[1].style.display = 'none';
    div[2].style.display = 'block';
  }
};
```

```css
.ButtonOveral {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: -15px;
}
.ButtonOveral2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 40px;
}
.ButtonOveral3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 100px;
}
.ButtonOveral4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 160px;
}
.ButtonOveral5 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 220px;
}
.ButtonOveral6 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 280px;
}
.Red {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 85px;
  left: 4px;
  top: 350px;
}
/*
pointer-events: none; // enables you to click through transparent divs
*/

img {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 34px;
  top: 562px;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -33px;
}
.moneyHolder {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 810px;
  background-color: red;
  left: 83px;
  top: -8px;
}
#newpost {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 83px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 810px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: green;
}
#SecondWindow {
  position: relative;
  left: 83px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 810px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: hsla(359, 35%, 39%, 0.35);
}
#ThirdWindow {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  left: 83px;
  top: -8px;
  width: 810px;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.upgradeHolder {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 90;
  height: 598;
  background-color: black;
}
.Lemon {
  width: 90px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: #B93437;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.Lemon2 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: purple;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.savebutton {
  width: 90px;
  height: 55px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
#button,
#button2,
#button3 {
  display: inline-block;
  background: hsla(39, 100%, 50%, 0.59);
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="moneyHolder">
  <h1 style="cursor:default"> Money: <span id="money">0</span></h1>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div class="WindowTwo" id="SecondWindow">
    <p class="ButtonOveral" onclick="ProtoType()" id="tooltip22">Price: <span id="RedId1">0</span> 
      </br>Bank: <span id="Reds1">0</span>
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="WindowThree" id="ThirdWindow"></div>

  <div class="container" id="newpost" onclick="GatherMoney()">

    <div class="Lemon" onclick="Build(0);">Lemon: <span id="Building1Cost">0</span>
      </br>PerSec: <span id="Building1PerSec">1</span>
      </br>Quantity: <span id="Building1Qty">0</span> 
    </div>

    <div class="saveButton" style="cursor:default" onclick="save()">
      <h2>Save </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Below is "window" changer 
-->
</div>
<div class="upgradeHolder">
  <div id="button" onclick="toggleDiv(0)">one</div>
  <div id="button2" onclick="toggleDiv(1)">two</div>
  <div id="button3" onclick="toggleDiv(2)">Three</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `getElementsByTagName` for this. It will select all `div`s that are a descendant of `wrapper`. use `children` instead. All your elements in `wrapper` are "window" *divs*. So if you use this it will work as you intended.

```
function toggleDiv(target){
  var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').children;
  if (target == 1) {
      div[0].style.display = 'block';
      div[1].style.display = 'none';
      div[2].style.display = 'none';
  } else if(target == 2) {
      div[0].style.display = 'none';
      div[1].style.display = 'block';
      div[2].style.display = 'none';
  }else{
      div[0].style.display = 'none';
      div[1].style.display = 'none';
      div[2].style.display = 'block';

  }

};
```

Or an even better solution:

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll("#wrapper > div");
```

This selects only direct descendants (children) of `wrapper` that or of the type `div`.

Comment: Thank you very much, couldn't wrap my head around that one. :) appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/g1x18owL/

Your selector is wrong as it gets all `divs` that are contained within `wrapper`

Change it to `children` to receive only the direct decendents of the `wrapper` div and also amend your if statement.

I.e.

```
window.toggleDiv = function (target) {
    var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').children;
    if (target == 0) {
        div[0].style.display = 'block';
        div[1].style.display = 'none';
        div[2].style.display = 'none';
    } else if (target == 1) {
        div[0].style.display = 'none';
        div[1].style.display = 'block';
        div[2].style.display = 'none';
    } else if (target == 2) {
        div[0].style.display = 'none';
        div[1].style.display = 'none';
        div[2].style.display = 'block';

    }

}
```